# Tableau Format Percentage Pie Chart

Tags: pie-chart, tableau-api, calculated-field

I created pie chart in tableau, i.e

[image]

When I try to format number into percentage, I get this

[image]

How would I even create a calculated value. Data is in the form

```
TYPE
Email
Removable Media
HTTP
CD/DVD
```

For all values, filtered by `Location`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the measure that's in the Text field, and select "Quick Table Calculation" / "Percent of Total". That oughta do it for you.